# How to stop Visual Studio 2019 auto formatting my Designer file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, resharper, windows-forms-designer

I am struggling to find a solution to stop Visual studio to `Auto Format` my `.Designer.vb` file.

I have turned off `Pretty Listing` under

```
Options > Text Editor > Basic > Advanced
```

However it still wants to format my designer file when I save changes.

Here are one example when I compare against original

Previous

```
Me._lstview_ColumnHeader_1 = CType(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader(),System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)
```

After Saving

```
Me._lstview_ColumnHeader_1= CType(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader(), System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)
```

You can see above it has added space between `, System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader`

Many places has had the above.

Also some places have had bracket `()` removed and `True` changed to `true`

I am not exactly sure what else could be causing this?

I am also using ReSharper and have `turned off` the following options and still no luck

- Auto-format on semicolon
- Auto-format on closing brace
- Auto-insert closing brace

Am I missing something?

Comment: Those ReSharper settings relate specifically to C# so how could they make a difference?

Comment: @jmcilhinney it was a try to stop the formatting to be applied on save ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can't stop it because it's not happening. Your designer code file isn't being reformatted. It's being rewritten. That's exactly why it is recommended that you don't make changes to that file by hand. Every time you make changes in the designer, the IDE rewrites that file. That's it, that's all. Generally speaking, the only reason that you should be making changes in that file is if a VS bug broke it and you need to fix it. Other genuine reasons might include replacing a standard control with a derived control that adds functionality. You shouldn't really care what the designer code file looks like anyway, because you should pretty much never be in there.

Comment: make sense about rewritten. But then I am sure there is something forcing the formatting to be applied to the designer file. Any control added etc brings about all these changes. When you are doing a PR and peer see alot of changes to the designer file raises the question as to why so many changes? Also when doing future review of past changes it will mislead the developer to thing that so many changes were made when the original request for e.g. was to add or move a control. Hope you understand I mean?